# Read IIS log files using PHP

Tags: php, iis

Anybody knows how to read IIS log files using PHP?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  They're files, right?  Not some wacky registry hilarity, right?  Just opening them should work just fine.

Comment: I tried file manipulation functions in PHP but no luck, My website is running in a web hosting environment. Is there anything i could do?

Comment: If you're in a commercial web hosting environment, you almost certainly won't have permission to read the files.  You should probably ask your hosting provider about that.

Comment: Thanks Charles for the response, I think thats what i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try the fopen() using the complete path to the logs, e.g. `fopen("C:\web\arnold\logs.txt", "R");`